# SSRS if IsNothing color expressions

Tags: reporting-services

I am trying to color my rows based on certain conditions if matched.

As I test I started with

```
=Switch(IsNothing(Fields!new_submittalactualdate.Value), “RED”, IsNothing(Fields!new_correctionsactualdate.Value), "BLUE")
```

Which worked fine But I need to refine it more So I tried

```
=Switch(IsNothing(Fields!new_submittalactualdate.Value), “RED”, IsNothing(Fields!new_correctionsactualdate.Value) AND IIF(IsNothing(Fields!new_correctionsrequireddate.Value),"" "BLUE"
```

So what I am trying to accomplish is if `Fields!new_correctionsactualdate.Value` is blank and `Fields!new_correctionsrequireddate.Value` contains data then make that line blue but I seem to be missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to check if a field contains data is to use a `NOT` on your `IsNothing()` like:

```
=Switch(IsNothing(Fields!new_submittalactualdate.Value), “RED”
       , IsNothing(Fields!new_correctionsactualdate.Value) 
         AND NOT IsNothing(Fields!new_correctionsrequireddate.Value), "BLUE")
```

Comment: Thank you that works perfect did not know I could do it that way.